Schumann / Scenes from Childhood
In the first piece of Schumann's Scenes from Childhood (titled "About Strange Lands and People") the first measure, in the bass clef, has two 1/8 rests.
However, the first measure of the second part, also in the bass clef, the timing is the same but there are no rests.
Why are there rests in one measure but not in another measure?

Good observation that I wish more pianists would pay more attention to in order to respect to the composer's intention, especially because this Schumann's very famous Kinderszenen album features pictorial impressionistic pieces.
Note values and Voices
First, note that the difference of the first measure of both sections extends throughout the each section.  But the timing of the bass line notes (see Divizna's answer to identify the voices) is not the same between both sections: 1/8 notes in the first section but 1/4 notes in the second section, which explains the 1/8 rests in the first section.  Although the onset of every bass line notes is the same for both sections, which is every beat (every 1/4).
Rendering instructions and their markings
Also note that in the second section bass line there are slurs every 2 measures, matching the phrasing slurs of the melody line. Coupled with the 1/8 rest after every bass line note in the first section, this indicates that Schumann may have meant the bass line to sound more detached in the first section rather than legato in the second section, adding to the contrast of mood between the two sections (first section being light and cheery, second section being more sad, serious and reflective).
Pedaling annotations
About pedal use, there is an interesting history of annotations in the various editions courtesy of IMSLP:

There are no pedal markings in the (official?) Clara Schumann edited Breitkopf & Härtel 1880 edition (pdf here), suggesting pedal is to be used only to assist connecting notes rather than to prolong them beyond the note values.  An first edition (possibly 1839 reissued 1845, see here) has a single Ped sign (con pedale), suggesting pedaling can be used at the pianist's discretion, in contrast with senza pedale that says no pedal is to be used.  (This senza pedale marking is not used in any of the album pieces.)

Modern editions (including the one I used when I was a kid) seems to follow a later edition with annotations by Leopold Godowsky published in 1915 (pdf here) where there are copious Ped signs (which in turn is followed by @Divzna's linked MuseScore copy).  There is a disclaimer in the beginning that the edition is a

Carefully Revised Edition with Fingering, Pedaling, and Instructive Annotations by Leopold Godowsky


Alfred Music Publisher's edition (still in print) is more circumspect, carefully indicating which marks come from Clara Schumman's edition and which ones are from later editors, by printing them in a lighter grayscale font (see example here).


Bringing it all together
So how should a pianist use the pedal for this piece?

Regardless of the pedaling technique used, because the bass line notes consistently occur in every beat throughout the piece (plus 3 special passing notes in section 2, which cries out "I'm special"), you have to use this voice as the pace-setter as well as the arch-setter (along with the melody).  For that reason, even though there are 1/8 rests, regardless of the pedaling technique used, the audience should hear the bass line as a smooth flowing understructure supporting the 2 upper voices.

But Schumann's instruction is clear: the bass line is notated detached in the first section and legato in the second section for a reason, and must therefore be rendered appropriately, a failing by too many beginning pianists (including myself when I was little).  The audience must hear the detached vs. legato contrast between the two sections while hearing the smooth flow of the bass line.


Therefore, your challenge is how to use the pedal judiciously while achieving both goals above, depending on the piano and the room (less pedal for 9' grand in a concert hall, more pedal for an upright piano in an apartment).  Example: Although Martha Argerich renders the piece with pedaling throughout first section (we don't hear the rests, only the natural falling off of the 1/8 notes), she makes the second section bass line a lot more prominent voice by holding the line without lifting her finger.  Similarly, Vladimir Horowitz.

Thank you for your reply

@Linda I added performance tips and about interpreting the pedal markings, also an example of how a pianist should process all the markings in order to produce beautiful rendering of the pieces in the album.

Not sure what you mean.
If you mean this

versus this

then what I see is basically three voices: One firmly in the treble clef, one in the triplets between the clefs, and one firmly in the bass clef below.
In the first bar, the lowest voice goes eighth note - eighth rest - eighth note - eighth rest.
In the bar after the repeat, the lowest voice goes quarter note - quarter note.
I can tell the eighth notes from quarter notes by one or none flag on their stems (pointing down).
(Screenshots from here.)

I would note that Schumann's metronome marking is quarter note = 108.
